# Four boxes and 2 rows scalable layout

Tags: html, css

Cannot figure out how to do the following layout in html/css:

```
 [ ][ ][ ][ ]
 [ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

4 boxes in 2 rows with 20px gap between them.
4 boxes widths + 3 gaps widths should stretch to the container div box which is fluid.

Thanks for help with this.

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Comment: use whatever % you need of the container's width: http://jsfiddle.net/LSZLC/